# androidannotations @AfterViews is not calling and editText is null

Tags: android, xml, android-annotations

I have a class and it extends from Fragment. Inside a class my editText is null and @AfterViews is not calling here is my code:

```
@EFragment
public class Search extends Fragment {

private final String TAG = Search.class.getCanonicalName();
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container, false);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");
    return rootView;
}
@ViewById
RadioButton firstRadio;

@ViewById
RadioButton secondRadio;

@ViewById(R.id.editText1)
EditText editText1;

@AfterViews
void afterViews() {
    int a = 1;
    a++;
    Log.i(TAG, editText1 + "AfterViews");
    Log.i(TAG, a + "aaaaaaaa");
}

private void extractUrlsFromText(String s) {
    Matcher matcher = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find())
        urlList.add(matcher.group());
}

public void searchWebUrl() {
    Log.i(TAG, editText1 + "searchWebUrl");
    String text = editText1.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text))
        extractUrlsFromText(text);
        parseWithUrls(urlList);
        ((Main) getActivity()).switchToFragmentUrlList(urlList);
}
```

}

Please help me why editText is null thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to let `AndroidAnnotations` handle the layout inflation and inject the view reference:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.my_fragment_layout)
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @ViewById(R.id.my_text_view) // must exist in layout, must be of correct type
    TextView mTextView;

    @AfterViews
    void initViews() {
        mTextView.setText("Hello World");
    }
}
```

An then use the generated class with `_` prefix.

Comment: I've already done this but my xml is not being rendered. If i write "View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container, false);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");
    return rootView;" inside onCreateVies it will display.

Comment: @nAkhmedov Clear generated classes, compile again. Use the newly generated `_` class. If it does not generate, there's an issue with setup.

Comment: I called Search class method in the followinf in Main Activity

Comment: ((Search) pagerAdapter.getCurrFragment()).searchWebUrl();

Comment: Should "@EFragment(R.layout.my_fragment_layout)" be rendered layout?layout is only being displayed if i write inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container, false) inside onCreateView.

Comment: if i use _ like ((Search_) pagerAdapter.getCurrFragment()).searchWebUrl(); class cast exception is appeared. cannot cast Search to Search_

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the exact same issue